# KVM Switch for a Gaming PC and a new Macbook?

Tags: kvm, thunderbolt

I have a Gaming PC and a newer Macbook. I want to connect these two to a monitor (displayport, 2k 144hz), keyboard/mouse (2 USB 2.0), and headset (speaker/mic).

So, I am looking for a KVM (or similar) switch that:

Outputs:

- Displayport (2k, 144hz)
- 2x USB 2.0
- Audio (speaker/mic)

Inputs:

- Group 1 (Macbook):

  - Thunderbolt 3
- Group 2 (PC):

  - Displayport
  - USB (2x?)
  - Audio (speaker/mic)

Does such a device exist?